# Will using Qt in a big MFC Windows-only app speed up development?

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

I know there is a lot of Qt vs MFC questions, but I'll try to be very specific.

We have a big (10 years of development) C++ MFC application for niche industry. It's supposed to stay Windows-only and English-only forever. But we need to add a bunch of new designer-drawn GUIs and GUI controls (dialogs, buttons, custom lists, ...).

We can hire 1 or 2 new GUI developers to build these new interfaces, so we can afford to choose different technology than MFC.

Qt seems most promising and suitable to run side-by-side with MFC (oh, no, we are not reduilding the app from scratch).

It seems that most cited Qt advantages are irrelevant: cross-platform development, easy internationalization, opensource, non-GUI libraries (we don't need networking and have most of other features already implemented).

But Qt is also famous for its good OO design and they've introduced QtQuick recently. I'd like to give it a chance, so the questions are

- **In a commercial Windows-only project, what are substantional advantages of moving to MFC+Qt** from of pure MFC, which is worth the trouble of learning Qt, integrating it in our build/deploy process and maybe paying for a commercial license?
- **In particular, will it speed-up the development** if we build new GUIs in Qt and incorporate them in the app via QWinWidget?

Comment: I'd be curious to know how you run MFC and Qt together, I would have thought it impossible - there can be only one message loop.

Comment: All my spider senses are telling me that this is a bad idea, it's almost guaranteed you'll spend more effort than it's worth to maintain a consistent state between MFC & QT.

Comment: @MarkRansom, http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/qtwinmigrate/index.html

Comment: @Steed: I'd be a bit worried by the fact that (from the looks of things) that hasn't been updated since 2004. If you're using a newer version of MFC (especially since 2008 SP1, when a lot was added to MFC) I'd plan on some testing before depending on that code.

Comment: Very interesting, it works by replacing key bits of both MFC and Qt with a superset. I'm tempted to agree with @Ylisar though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, oops, it seems I've Google'd the wrong link. They have a never version from 2009: http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/index.html. But it's still not 2013, so I definitely agree, thank you.

Comment: What a pity that a question got closed without any explaination. I tried to make the question as specific as possible. So how can I improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not.

If the gui and business logic are nicely separated then it might make sense to move the gui gradually to Qt or implement new parts in Qt - but we both know the gui/logic will be a horrible mixed together mess

If you are doing a rewrite (which is what the Qt will end up as) then if it's a regular business type app then using C#/.net is probably easier.

If performance is critical and you have a lot of domain knowledge tied up in well defined well separated c++ libs then a Qt front end would be worthwhile

Comment: Thank you, Martin. Yes, perfomance is critical and code base is huge, and, yes, we have poor gui/logic separation. .NET was our first idea, but even compiling the app with C++/CLI would be a pain, not to mention rewriting in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Not basically answer to a question, but might be helpful as weel. I think another way to do GUI with newer tools is to use ActiveX and COM. I believe you can easily use ActiveX components in your MFC applications. Also there are many ways to create such controls. I was using Delphi to do controls that were successfully used in .NET WinForms applications, but as far as I know such controls can be created in .NET environment with little effort.